# Get real file name (case sensitive)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I work with node on Windows. I execute `node folder/app`.

Now I want to find name of main file of my app `process.mainModule.filename` and exactly I receive `drive/folder/app.js`.

But I need to receive `drive/folder/App.js` because this is a real name of file.

Which is the simplest way to resolve this?

Comment: windows is case insensitive so it wont matter. in any other Os you will get exact name

Comment: I'm confused, why are you executing the lowercase version? If you execute the uppercase one, odes it also resolve to lowercase?

Comment: @loganfsmyth, no, if I execute uppercase all works fine.

Comment: "windows is case insensitive", seriously I know it! I only ask how I can receive real file name, because some parts of program are case sensitive.

Comment: I don't have a windows machine to test on, but have you tried `fs.realpath(process.mainModule.filename)`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth, unfortunately the result is same as initial path string =(

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct good way to determine the file-system is case-insensitive and get the real path across all os.

eg, '/proc/self/fd/[fd]' only on linux.

But there is a stupid way to do it across all os.

The compelete source code here: https://gist.github.com/snowyu/bdc39a93d25503333991

The following coffee-script code is just to show the principle:

```
folderIsInsensitive = (aFolder)->
  t = tmp.fileSync template:'./_tmp-XXXXXXXXX'
  result = fs.existsSync t.name.toUpperCase()
  t.removeCallback()
  return result

getRealPathForInsensitive = (aPath)->
  result = ''
  while aPath and aPath != path.sep
    basename = path.basename(aPath).toLowerCase()
    aPath = path.dirname aPath
    dirs  = fs.readdirSync aPath
    for dir in dirs
      if dir.toLowerCase() is basename
        result = path.join dir, result
        break
  return result
```